# What is a layer in a shapefile

Tags: python, gis

I am beginning to learn about GIS data. I am interested in looking in this data using Python. I am presently learning about the shapefiles. I am learning about the osgeo/ogr. I came across a `GetLayer()` method. Now I am not able to understand what a layer is in a shapefile. Is it necessary that a feature is added to a layer?

When I try to create multiple layers as follows :

```
shapeData = driver.CreateDataSource('customer_points.shp')
layer = shapeData.CreateLayer('customs', spatialReference, osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
layer = shapeData.CreateLayer('customs1', spatialReference, osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
```

What I get is shapefiles corresponding to `customer_points` with just one layer --- `GetLayer(0)` works, but `GetLayer(1)` returns `None`
Also I get shapefiles corresponding to `customs1`
So I am able to retrieve features added to `customs` NOT by reading 2nd layer from first shapefile, but by reading 1st layer from second shapefile

Comment: Can you provide some context on where you found the `GetLayer()` function (which library, software, etc.)? Shapefiles themselves do not have layers, I think you got something confused. I'll try to explain later, or someone else can.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the [OGRDataSource class](http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/classOGRDataSource.html) It says that a `OGRDataSource` consists *potentially* of many `OGRLayer` objects.
Also see Python [osgeo.ogr.DataSource](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.DataSource-class.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that ESRI shapefile format does not support grouping features into separate layers.

However OGR provides an abstract source for vector data in the form of [osgeo.ogr.DataSource](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.DataSource-class.html) that does assume that the features are grouped into one or more layers. The layers are numbered starting from 0 and `osgeo.ogr.DataSource.GetLayer(self, iLayer=0)` function provides a convenient default to extract data from the first layer which happens to be the only layer when the data source is a shapefile.

If you want to save vector data into a shapefile, according to OGR model you have to create a layer with `osgeo.ogr.DataSource.CreateLayer(self, *args, **kwargs)` and add features to this layer object.

Comment: ok I understand better now. What I also want to know is that while working with `osdeo.odr.DataSource` does it make sense to create a shapefile with multiple layers

Comment: @user3282758 this is a good question. I cannot answer immediately. Perhaps you can edit/rephrase your question to make clear what you are asking, or ask a separate question.